# Best way to call an asynchronous function within map?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm mapping over an array and for one of the return values of the new object, I need to make an asynchronous call.

```
var firebaseData = teachers.map(function(teacher) {
  return {
    name: teacher.title,
    description: teacher.body_html,
    image: urlToBase64(teacher.summary_html.match(/src="(.*?)"/)[1]),
    city: metafieldTeacherData[teacher.id].city,
    country: metafieldTeacherData[teacher.id].country,
    state: metafieldTeacherData[teacher.id].state,
    studioName: metafieldTeacherData[teacher.id].studioName,
    studioURL: metafieldTeacherData[teacher.id].studioURL
  }
});
```

The implementation of that function will look something like

```
function urlToBase64(url) {
  request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      return "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer(body).toString('base64');
    }
  });
}
```

I'm not clear what's the best approach to do this... promises? Nested callbacks? Use something in ES6 or ES7 and then transpile with Babel?

What's the current best way to implement this?

Comment: Maybe taka a look at https://github.com/caolan/async map function

Comment: You would have to implement either callbacks or promises in the function you are using inside map.

Comment: To run Promises (wrappers) *sequentially*, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57722131/3779853)

Comment: Probably [a good introduction in using of async functions inside Array.map](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-async-functions-with-array-map-in-javascript/) was suggested by Tamás Sallai. As a result use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) where possible.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

One approach is [`Promise.all` (ES6)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

This answer will work in Node 4.0+. Older versions will need a Promise polyfill or library. I have also used ES6 arrow functions, which you could replace with regular `function`s for Node < 4.

This technique manually wraps `request.get` with a Promise. You could also use a library like [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise).

```
function urlToBase64(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        resolve("data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer(body).toString('base64'));
      } else {
        reject(response);
      }
    });
  })
} 

// Map input data to an Array of Promises
let promises = input.map(element => {
  return urlToBase64(element.image)
    .then(base64 => {
      element.base64Data = base64;
      return element;
    })
});

// Wait for all Promises to complete
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(results => {
    // Handle results
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
  })
```

Comment: Pretty generic code if you ask me. How would that look like with the code he has given?

Comment: Plus I think he wants to use it on server side with Node.js, since he asked for promises I expect him to use the latest version. I'm interested in that myself, I currently use callbacks for mapping over an array with asynchron requests, store the amount of requests + requests done and execute the finishing function (which is the callback for all requests) only if all requests are done. Promises.all looks like a more elegant way to do that.

Comment: Thanks @joews I updated NodeJS to v5 and this code worked great.

Comment: That's the only syntax that worked for me for async function inside map

Answer (score 184):

update in 2018: `Promise.all` async function within map callback is easier to implement:

```
    let firebaseData = await Promise.all(teachers.map(async teacher => {
        return {
            name: teacher.title,
            description: teacher.body_html,
            image: await urlToBase64(teacher.summary_html.match(/src="(.*?)"/)[1]),
            city: metafieldTeacherData[teacher.id].city,
            country: metafieldTeacherData[teacher.id].country,
            state: metafieldTeacherData[teacher.id].state,
            studioName: metafieldTeacherData[teacher.id].studioName,
            studioURL: metafieldTeacherData[teacher.id].studioURL
        }
    }));


async function urlToBase64(url) {
  return request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      return "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer(body).toString('base64');
    }
  });
}
```

`Edit@2018/04/29`: I put the general example for everyone:

`Edit@2019/06/19` : async/await should have try/catch to handle errors to make your process continue working in case of some of requests failed.

```
let data = await Promise.all(data.map(async (item) => {
      try {
      item.fetchItem = await fetchFunc(item.fetchParams);

      return item; 
      } catch(error) {
         return {...item, error } ;
      }
  }));
  /* we can filter errors in data and retry later 
   * eg:
   * const errorItems = data.filter(item => !!item.error)
   */
```

Comment: what is the point of keeping the map callback function async, if fetchFunc is returning promise, then Promise.all should take care of resolving all the promises. I feel it is only required when you want to resolve all the promises sequentially.

Comment: the `.map()` function will return an array of `Promise`, and `Promise.all()` will do resolve that parallel. That syntax might confuse you with `return item`, it looks like just return a variable not the promise: but that syntax equal to `function() { item = data[i]; return new Promise(resolve => fetchFunc().then(result => {item.fetchItem = result;  resolve(item);  } )}`

Comment: *"...`Promise.all()` will do resolve that parallel."*: No, `Promise.all` does nothing to the promises. It only creates a new promise that resolves when the given ones have all resolved. The latter would happen anyway, even if you don't call `Promise.all`.

Comment: @trincot I think my words were not clear at that time: it should be Promise.all creates a `Promise` that will wait till all `Child Promises` be resolved then resolve itself. Is it fine? Thanks for the catch :D

Answer (score 20):

In 2020 we now have the [`for await...of` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) of [ECMAScript2021](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements) that significantly simplifies things:

So you can now simply do this:

```
//return an array of promises from our iteration:
let promises = teachers.map(async m => {
   return await request.get(....);
});

//simply iterate those
//val will be the result of the promise not the promise itself
for await (let val of promises){
   ....
}
```

Comment: The ECMAscript standards body has taken us full circle now. In the dark early days of JS we were stuck with `for` loops for everything (or we had to use jQuery, Lodash, etc. to get a `map`).  Then came ES2015, and devs everywhere rejoiced at finally being able to use map.  But now we're back to being stuck with `for` loops again, at least for `await` code ... two steps forward, one step back :(

Comment: @Liam: Where do you put return {name: teacher.title, description: teacher.body_html,
    image: urlToBase64(teacher.summary_html.match(/src="(.*?)"/)[1]), etc. in you example?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [async.map](http://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#map).

```
var async = require('async');

async.map(teachers, mapTeacher, function(err, results){
  // results is now an array of stats for each file
});

function mapTeacher(teacher, done) {
  // computing stuff here...
  done(null, teacher);
}
```

note that all teachers will be processed in parallel - you can use also this functions:

`mapSeries(arr, iterator, [callback])` maps one by one

`mapLimit(arr, limit, iterator, [callback])` maps `limit` at same time

Comment: it has a lodash dependency... not that there's anything wrong with that. async@2.6.1 ~ lodash@4.17.11

Comment: being able to limit number of simultaneous async functions is crucial

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and found this to be easier (I'm using Kai's generic template). Below, you only need to use one `await`. I was also using an ajax function as my async function:

```
function asyncFunction(item) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: response => {
            console.log("response received:", response);
            return response;
        }, error: err => {
            console.log("error in ajax", err);
        }
    });
}

let data = await Promise.all(data.map(item => asyncFunction(item)));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try **amap()**, the asynchronous map function below:

```
async function amap(arr,fun) {
    return await Promise.all(arr.map(async v => await fun(v)))
}
```

Or, written in a more concise way:

```
let amap = async (arr,fun) => await Promise.all(arr.map(async v => await fun(v)))
```

Usage:

```
let arr = await amap([1,2,3], async x => x*2)
console.log(arr)   // [2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using an async function over the array. And not using array.map, but a for function. It's something like this:

```
const resultingProcessedArray = async function getSomeArray() {
    try {
      let { data } = await axios({url: '/myUrl', method:'GET'}); //initial array
      let resultingProcessedArray = [];
      for (let i = 0, len = data.items.length; i < len; i++) {
        let results = await axios({url: `/users?filter=id eq ${data.items[i].someId}`, method:'GET'});
        let domainName = results.data.items[0].domainName;
        resultingProcessedArray.push(Object.assign(data.items[i], {domainName}));
      }
      return resultingProcessedArray;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Unable to fetch the data", err);
      return [];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to write this, for the sake of convenience. Otherwise, I might need https://github.com/mcollina/make-promises-safe

```js
export async function mapAsync<T, U>(
  arr: T[], 
  callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => Promise<U>, 
  thisArg?: any
) {
  return await Promise.all(arr.map(async (value, index, array) => {
    try {
      return await callbackfn(value, index, array);
    } catch(e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }, thisArg));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For production purposes you probably want to use a lib like [lodasync](https://github.com/nick-keller/lodasync), you should not reinvent the wheel:

```js
import { mapAsync } from 'lodasync'

const result = await mapAsync(async(element) => {
  return 3 + await doSomething(element)
}, array)
```

It uses promises, has no dependencies, and is as fast as it gets.

Comment: A potential issue with the implementation of mapAsync is that all elements will be processed simultaneously. This may or may not be desirable (e.g. you're hitting a website, which could overload the server). The async library described in another library has mapLimit which allows you to limit how many functions to run at once.

Answer (score 1):

By using **Promise.all** you can make **map** and **forEach** work with async functions (i.e. Promises).

To make **filter**, **some** and **every** work you can first use an async map (that in turn uses Promise.all) and then go through the true/false values and synchronously do the filtering/evaluation.

To make **reduce** and **reduceRight** work with async functions you can wrap the original function in a new one that waits for the accumulator to resolve.

Using this knowledge it is possible to modify the original array methods in a way so that they continue to work "as usual" with normal/synchronous functions but will also work with async functions.

```
// a 'mini library' (save it somewhere and import it once/project)
(() => {
  let AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async e => e).constructor;
  ['map', 'forEach'].forEach(method => {
    let orgMethod = Array.prototype[method];
    Array.prototype[method] = function (func) {
      let a = orgMethod.call(this, func);
      return func instanceof AsyncFunction ? Promise.all(a) : a;
    };
  });
  ['filter', 'some', 'every'].forEach(method => {
    let orgMethod = Array.prototype[method];
    Array.prototype[method] = function (func) {
      if (func instanceof AsyncFunction) {
        return (async () => {
          let trueOrFalse = await this.map(func);
          return orgMethod.call(this, (_x, i) => trueOrFalse[i]);
        })();
      }
      else {
        return orgMethod.call(this, func);
      }
    };
  });
  ['reduce', 'reduceRight'].forEach(method => {
    let orgMethod = Array.prototype[method];
    Array.prototype[method] = function (...args) {
      if (args[0] instanceof AsyncFunction) {
        let orgFunc = args[0];
        args[0] = async (...args) => {
          args[0] = await args[0];
          return orgFunc.apply(this, args);
        };
      }
      return orgMethod.apply(this, args);
    };
  });
})();

// AND NOW:

// this will work
let a = [1, 2, 3].map(x => x * 3); // => [3, 6, 9]
let b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].filter(x => x > 3); // [4, 5, 6, 7]
let c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce((acc, val) => acc + val); // => 15

// this will also work
let x = await [1, 2, 3].map(async x => x * 3);
let y = await [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].filter(async x => x > 3);
let z = await [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(async (acc, val) => acc + val);
```

Comment: your note on `filter` saved me!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to map over all elements concurrently:

```js
function asyncMap(arr, fn) {
  return Promise.all(arr.map(fn));
}
```

If you'd like to map over all elements non-concurrently (e.g. when your mapping function has side effects or running mapper over all array elements at once would be too resource costly):

Option A: Promises

```js
function asyncMapStrict(arr, fn) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const result = [];
    arr.reduce(
      (promise, cur, idx) => promise
        .then(() => fn(cur, idx, arr)
          .then((res) => {
            result.push(res);
          })),
      Promise.resolve(),
    ).then(() => resolve(result));
  });
}
```

Option B: async/await

```js
async function asyncMapStrict(arr, fn) {
  const result = [];

  for (let idx = 0; idx < arr.length; idx += 1) {
    const cur = arr[idx];

    result.push(await fn(cur, idx, arr));
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion the cleanest and most to the point of all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to call an async function within `map` is to use a `map` created expressly for async functions.

For a function to be async, it must return a Promise.

```js
function urlToBase64(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error)
      } else if (response && response.statusCode == 200) {
        resolve(
          "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer(body).toString('base64');
        )
      } else {
        reject(new Error('invalid response'))
      }
    });
  })
}
```

Now, we can map:

```js
const { pipe, map, get } = require('rubico')

const metafieldTeacherData = {} // { [teacher_id]: {...}, ... }

const parseTeacher = teacher => ({
  name: teacher.title,
  description: teacher.body_html,
  image: urlToBase64(teacher.summary_html.match(/src="(.*?)"/)[1]),
  city: metafieldTeacherData[teacher.id].city,
  country: metafieldTeacherData[teacher.id].country,
  state: metafieldTeacherData[teacher.id].state,
  studioName: metafieldTeacherData[teacher.id].studioName,
  studioURL: metafieldTeacherData[teacher.id].studioURL
})

const main = async () => {
  const teachers = [] // array full of teachers
  const firebaseData = await map(pipe([
    parseTeacher,
    get('studioURL'),
    urlToBase64,
  ]))(teachers)
  console.log(firebaseData) // > ['data:application/json;base64,...', ...]
}

main()
```

rubico's map worries about `Promise.all` so you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Using IIFE and Promise.all, can make a simple use cases.

```
await Promise.all(arr.map(el=>(async _=>{
    // some async code       
})()))
```

This IIFE can return a promise which is used as the return value for map function.

```
(async _=>{
    // some async code       
})()
```

So arr.map will return a list of promise to Promise.all to handle.

Example

```
const sleep = (ms) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(_ => {
      resolve()
    }, ms)
  });
}

await Promise.all([1000,2000,3000].map(el=>(async _=>{
    await sleep(el)
    console.log(el) 
    return el  
})()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function that will let you choose to `await` each mapping operation (`serial`) or run all mappings in `parallel`.

The mapper function need not return a `promise` either.

```js
    async function asyncMap(items, mapper, options = {
      parallel: true
    }) {
      if (options.parallel) {
        const promises = items.map(it => mapper(it))
        return Promise.all(promises)
      } else {
        const ret = []
        for (const item of items) {
          ret.push(await mapper(item))
        }
        return ret
      }
    }
}
```

Typescript Version

```
    async function asyncMap<T, V>(items: T[], mapper: (item: T) => V, options = {
      parallel: true
    }): Promise<V[]> {
      if (options.parallel) {
        const promises:Promise<V>[] = items.map(it => mapper(it))
        return Promise.all(promises)
      } else {
        const ret:V[] = []
        for (const item of items) {
          ret.push(await mapper(item))
        }
        return ret
      }
    }
```

A working snippet for science

```js
async function asyncMap(items, mapper, options = {
  parallel: true
}) {
  if (options.parallel) {
    const promises = items.map(it => mapper(it))
    return Promise.all(promises)
  } else {
    const ret = []
    for (const item of items) {
      ret.push(await mapper(item))
    }
    return ret
  }
}

// A test to multiply number by 2 after 50 milliseconds
function delay(num) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('resolving after ', Date.now() - start, 'ms')
      resolve(num * 2)

    }, 50)
  })
}

const start = Date.now();
(async() => {
  const data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  const resParallel = await asyncMap(data, it => delay(it))
  const resSerial = await asyncMap(data, it => delay(it), {
    parallel: false
  })
  console.log(data)
  console.log(resParallel)
  console.log(resSerial)

})();
```

Comment: Just a note for "science": the `parallel` here doesn't do anything at all. If you want to run the async callbacks in series, you need a different approach. You could do it in a simple procedural way with a good old `for`/`while` loop, implement the map with reduce.

Comment: Updated, but not a fan of reduce so used for loop.