# How to keep array order in observable when only called randomly?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array of objects that only sometimes require a service call. The objects that require a service call take awhile to fill, so I end up with an array of the objects that didn't require a service call and then the rest at the end.

I've tried async / await, promise, and just regular subscription. Im very shaky with rxjs so I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this with observables and pipable operators

```
public getComments(cars: any) {
  cars.forEach( async car => {
    if(car.status === '1') {

      // trying async / await
      let repairs = await this.service.getComments(car.carId)
      car.repairs = repairs
      this.carRepairs.push(car)

      // regular subscribe
      // this.service.getComments(car.carId).subscribe(result => {
      //   car.repairs = result
      //   this.carRepairs.push(car)
      // })

      // trying promise
      // this.service.getComments(car.carId).toPromise().then(result => {
      //   car.repairs = result
      // })
    } else {
      this.carRepairs.push(car)
    }
  })
}
```

If anyone knows of a better way to do this with rxjs and keep the order, I'd love to learn.

Comment: You could use `Promise.all` with a call to `map` and return `Promise.resolve(car)` in those cases where you don't need to make the call: [Best way to call an async function within map?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48273841/215552). This is a comment because you specifically ask for rxjs, not promises :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so first you're gona want to map all of your items into an observable, even if they don't need to be observables, then you join them together:

```
import {forkJoin, of} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';


public getComments$(cars: any) {
  const results$ = cars.map( car => { // map the array into observables
    if(car.status === '1') {

      // return service call observable
      return this.service.getComments(car.carId).pipe(
        // ** see note on this **
        map(repairs => Object.assign(car, {repairs})) // add result to car and map to the car
      );

    } else {
      // return mock observable;
      return of(car);
    }
  });

  // return all observables joined together
  return forkJoin(results$); 
}
```

then you can just call it and subscribe to the result:

```
this.getComments$(this.cars).subscribe(carRepairs => {
  // do whatever here
  this.carRepairs = carRepairs;
});
```

this will ensure that the `carRepairs` are in the same order as `cars`.. all the needed requests will run in parallel, but you could do this sequentially by using `concat` instead and slightly modifying your subscribe function, if you want to preserve some kind of cascade effect.

note: I preserved a side effect from your original code where you mutate the objects in your cars array, normally, I wouldn't do that and I'd do `Object.assign({}, car, {repairs})` to ensure I don't produce side effects. side effects and mutation are often a source of bugs and should be avoided when ever possible.

Comment: Oh wow - really detailed. I'm wondering since cars comes in as an observable if there's a way to do it in rxjs with just observables then? I have a select like `@Select(state.getCars) cars$: Observable<any>` and in my init I do `this.cars$.subscribe(cars => {
  if(cars) {
    this.getComments(cars)
  }
})`
Is there a way to do this on the observable cars$ that comes in?

Comment: of course, just `this.cars$.pipe(switchMap(cars => (cars) ?  this.getComments$(cars) : EMPTY))` especially if you don't actually need `this.cars`