# Execute promises map sequentially

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have written a function that is being called in a loop (map) and that function is using promises. Now, I want that function to run synchronously and exit before its next instance is called.

```js
function t1(){
  let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
  return Promise.map(arr1, (val) =>{
    const params = {
      "param1" : val1
    };
    return t2(params);
  });
}

function t2(event){
  return Promise.resolve()
  .then({
  //do something
  //code doesn't reach here in sync manner. all five instance are invoked and then code reaches here for first instance and so on
  })
  .then({
  //promise chaining. do something more
  })
}
```

t2 is beingcalled five times, but I want each instance to be called only after the instance before it has returned the value. 
Currently its not behaving like that but invoking the function five times in parallel.

I can't use async/await due to project limitations.

Comment: What is `Promise.map`? Are you using bluebird or some other promise library?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that `Promise.prototype.map`, like `forEach`, does not wait for asynchronous functions called inside it to complete. (No asynchronous call will ever be waited for unless you tell the interpreter to do so explicitly with `await` or `.then`)

Have `t1` await each call of `t2`:

```
async function t1(){
  let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
  const results = [];
  for (const val of arr1) {
    results.push(await t2(val));
  }
  return results;
}
```

Or if you want to use `reduce` instead of `async`/`await`:

```js
const delay = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 500));
function t1(){
  let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
  return arr1.reduce((lastProm, val) => lastProm.then(
    (resultArrSoFar) => t2(val)
      .then(result => [...resultArrSoFar, result])
  ), Promise.resolve([]));
}

function t2(event){
  return delay().then(() => {
    console.log('iter');
    return event;
  });
}

t1()
  .then(results => console.log('end t1', results));
```

Or, if you need the sequential functionality to be encapsulated in t2, then have t2 have a semi-persistent variable of the previous Promise it generated:

```js
const delay = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 500));
const t1 = () => {
  return Promise.all([1, 2, 3, 4].map(t2));
};

const t2 = (() => {
  let lastProm = Promise.resolve();
  return (event) => {
    const nextProm = lastProm
      .catch(() => null) // you may or may not want to catch here
      .then(() => {
        // do something with event
        console.log('processing event');
        return delay().then(() => event);
      });
    lastProm = nextProm;
    return nextProm;
  };
})();

t1().then(results => console.log('t1 done', results));
```

Comment: Instead of modifying `t2` to keep the queue itself, I'd recommend to just use the good ol' `reduce` approach in `t1`.

Comment: Could you also help me understand where I went wrong in my approach?

Comment: @user3807691 without an "await" all javascript code is just executed without waiting on anything. So sequential code will never wait until a promise is resolved. If you cannot use await, you will have to code logic, which starts only a single promise-based function and calls the next only in the callback (then)

Comment: @Falso thanks! helped me understand better. Although I was under the impression that if we use a 'return' statement, it will make promise to wait and hence run in sync.

Comment: @user3807691 Only `await` and `.then` makes the interpreter wait for a Promise to complete before moving on

Answer (score 1):

```
(function loop(index) {
    const next = promiseArray[index];
    if (!next) {
        return;
    }
    next.then((response) => {
        // do Something before next
        loop(index + 1);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
        loop(index + 1);
    });
})(0 /* startIndex */)
```

Comment: I would pass "index+1" as a parameter to the next invocation of loop(index), so we don't need to manage a global state variable (feels wrong, and can get messy, if we change "index" in other parts of the code...

Comment: I'd drop the `.catch()` thing. If there was an error, we don't want the loop to continue. We especially don't want it to continue if the error came from the recursive `loop(index + 1)` call.

Comment: Wait, what is `promiseArray`? If you don't construct the individual promises inside the `loop` itself, but create them before and put them into an array, they still won't run sequentially.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what running Promises sequentially would look like when using `.reduce()` in combination with async/await:

```js
async function main() {

  const t2 = (v) => Promise.resolve(v*2)
  const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
  
  const arr1_mapped = await arr1.reduce(async (allAsync, val) => {
    const all = await allAsync
    all.push(await t2(val) /* <-- your async transformation */) 
    return all
  }, [])

  console.log(arr1_mapped)

}

main()
```

Comment: Sorry, but why the downvotes? It works as expected, I'm using it myself. :D

Comment: a) Using `reduce` with `await` is horrible code b) OP explicitly stated that they cannot use `async`/`await`

Comment: Fair enough. I considered it to be a prettier alternative to what the accepted answer suggested in their `reduce` example. With Coffeescript, it even [looks pretty nice](https://tio.run/##LY3NCsMgEITveYo5piUsVOgxfYbeQw6imyKYKmrN49u1DSzsz3wza8K2MWeTXCyqNRswP4YBKAozxnqRFc8UdpeZEufgK6NelRA6JUGWG9F97Y5dx8hWTvrQrnRZDPZjGKP2fsIvSzhgARGdVFf@Y1H93SrEhKU3KRPe8pLJh9eZ39oX) in my opinion. Doesnt strictly answer the question though, you are right. :-)