# Recursive axios calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, ecmascript-6, promise

I am trying to return all the teams in a sports division. The api is as follows:

Call `/api/divs/ID`, which returns

- a list of subdivisions (`.divInfo`)
- a list of teams in that division (`.teams`)

For example, I called it with `Division 1` (`55720`), which gave me all the regions as well as a couple teams.

[image]
From any division, I am trying to assemble the complete list of teams in that division, **including** subdivisions.

Here is my code:

```
async getSubteams(id) {
    let vm = this
    return await this.$axios.get(`/api/div/${id}`).then(r => {
        let additionalTeams = r.data.divInfo.map(subDivision => vm.getSubteams(subDivision.DivIDDivision))
        return r.data.teams.concat(...additionalTeams)
    })
}
```

```
const teams = await this.getSubteams(this.id)
```

This does not give me the expected output of a list of team objects. Instead, it is a mix between Promises and teams.

[image]

I know this is incorrectly programmed, but how can I maintain the asynchrony of this (i.e. multiple api calls are happening at once) while getting a normal list without promises.

I have debated returning promises and then using `Promises.all(...)`, but that did not seem like the best approach.

Comment: I would say Promise.all is the best approach... Your code seems solid with the exception that you are not awaiting the `getSubteams()` calls. Hence why you are seeing the Promise result as opposed to the result.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438158/best-way-to-call-an-async-function-within-map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Promise.all` was the key.

```
async getSubteams(id) {
    let vm = this
    return await this.$axios.get(`/api/div/${id}`).then(async r => {
        let additionalTeams = await Promise.all(r.data.divInfo.map(subDivision => {
            return vm.getSubteams(subDivision.DivIDDivision)
        }))
        return r.data.teams.concat(...additionalTeams)
    })
}
```