# Sequelize.update() refuses to work in async function and doesn't update / doesn't await

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Consider the code:

```
const listOfEmployees = .... // get list of employees from god knows where ...
    
    
async function incrementHoursEmps(listOfEmployees) {
  listOfEmployees.map(async employeeId => {     
    const condition = { where : {employeeId} }; 
    const options = { multi: true };
    const values = { hoursWork: sequelize.literal('"hoursWork" + 1') };
    ModelEmployees.update(values, condition , options)
        .then(result => { 
            // ....
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
}
    
await incrementHoursEmps(listOfEmployees);
```

Whenever I try to update multiple rows (or even just a single row) using the `.update()` method of `Sequelize` , the code never awaits and the `.update()` doesn't really update.

Is it even working or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to call an asynchronous function within map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438158/best-way-to-call-an-asynchronous-function-within-map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.map` is not async aware. If you want to achieve this kind of setup you need to use `Array.map` to convert your list to promises, then use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to await on all promises and return an array of the results.

```js
const listOfEmployees = .... // get list of employees from god knows where ...
    
async function incrementHoursEmps(listOfEmployees) {
    return listOfEmployees.map(employeeId => {
        const condition = { where: { employeeId } };
        const options = { multi: true };
        const values = { hoursWork: sequelize.literal('"hoursWork" + 1') };
        return ModelEmployees.update(values, condition, options);
    });
}

await Promise.all(incrementHoursEmps(listOfEmployees));
```

Comment: Thanks , but it gives a `(node:24384) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))` ..... it returns an object and not an array of promises

Comment: Are you sure the list of employees is an array?