# How to add subscribe inside a map function in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am running into an issue where I would like to modify the objects inside an array based on data returned from a subscription.

```
this.options = this.options.map(data => {
      this.workflowTemplateService.getWorkflowTemplateStatistics(data.id).subscribe(res => {
        const available = (res.contactsInProgress + res.contactsInWaitingRoom + res.pausedCount).toString();
        const waitingRoomLimit = res.waitingRoomLimit;
        const quota = available.toString() + '/' + waitingRoomLimit.toString();
        console.log("Hit quota: ", quota);
        return {...data, quota};
      });
});
```

I wanted to do something like this where I would be able to add the quota property to each of the objects inside the array but I am getting an error related to returning void. I was wondering if there were another way where I would able to modify the options such that I can add the quota property into the options array.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.options$ = of(this.options)
.pipe(
  switchMap(data => this.workflowTemplateService.getWorkflowTemplateStatistics(data.id)),
  map(res => {
    const available = (res.contactsInProgress + res.contactsInWaitingRoom + res.pausedCount).toString();
        const waitingRoomLimit = res.waitingRoomLimit;
        const quota = available.toString() + '/' + waitingRoomLimit.toString();
        console.log("Hit quota: ", quota);
        return {...data, quota};
  })
)
```

Now you can suscribe directly to this.options$ which is now an observable or you can used directly in the template like `options$ | async`

```
this.options$.suscribe(res => console.log(res))
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you should convert your observable to promise to be able to take the advantage of using async/await.
You can convert your observable to promise by using `firstValueFrom` operator in rxjs to take the first value emitted and close the subscription after that.

```
const promise = firstValueFrom(this.workflowTemplateService.getWorkflowTemplateStatistics(data.id));
```

By converting your observable to a promise, now you can mark the `map` callback function as `async`. Here is the link about async map callback function:

[Best way to call an asynchronous function within map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438158/best-way-to-call-an-asynchronous-function-within-map)

and your result would be something like below

```
async updateOptions() {
   this.options = await Promise.all(
      this.options.map(async data => {
      const result = await firstValueFrom(this.workflowTemplateService.getWorkflowTemplateStatistics(data.id));
      ...
      return {...data, quota};
      })
   )
}
```

Comment: Using promises inside of RxJS operators is surely a red flag. It's so easy to introduce bugs that way (they have different execution semantics). Using promises inside an RxJS `map` operator is doubly bad. `Map` is meant to synchronously apply some transformation to each value, you can use higher order operators to map into async values 